PostgreSQL json testing (`is json`) and casting with null character (`\u0000`) work unexpectedly
I know something about null characters in PostgreSQL text types. But I cannot understand the strange behavior of json testing and casting:
select '{"foo":"bar\u0000"}' is json; --TRUE
select '{"foo":"bar\u0000"}'::json; --JSON
select '{"foo":"bar\u0000"}'::json->'foo'; --ERROR
--ERROR:  unsupported Unicode escape sequence
--DETAIL:  \u0000 cannot be converted to text.
--CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: {"foo":"bar\u0000...

Why string with null character is json (in terms of is json construction), casts to json (via ::json), but returns an error on json property access (::json->'foo')?
SELECT version(); --PostgreSQL 16.4 on aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 7.3.1 20180712 (Red Hat 7.3.1-17), 64-bit

UPD
I know that this issue has a workaround - replacing null characters from the text before doing json casting and accessing.
But the main problem there as I see it is that this behavior makes is json construction effectively useless when I want to test that some text is in the correct json format. As a user I expect that something correct in terms of is json will lead me to the ability to cast text to json and work with it.

As per the Postgres documentation, the Unicode escape sequence is allowed in json type. However, when you try to extract a json field out of the json type, I believe Postgres tries to convert it to an equivalent type (eg. '{"foo":"bar\u0000"}'::json->'foo' to text) where null byte u/0000 is not allowed in string/text.
You may have to do some workaround to get rid of these codes from your data before storing them in your database. Please refer to this answer.

Thank you for your answer! As said in the reference, I can deal with null characters by replacing them.
But the main problem there as I see it is that this behavior makes is json construction effectively useless when I want to test that some text is in the correct json format. As a user I expect that something correct in terms of is json will lead me to the ability to cast text to json and work with it.

About your guess - why does this conversion happen during accessing and not during casting and testing?
That is not because foo prop is text. This will work the same way if it is json - select '{"foo":{"baz":"bar\u0000"}}'::json->'foo'; --ERROR
I don't pretty understand the mechanics there and I wonder if is this some kind of bug or just some tricky under-the-hood behavior.

As per my understanding, the json type in Postgres doesn't do much validation whereas the jsonb type does some kind of validation. select {"foo":"bar\u0000"}'::jsonb will throw an exception as it contains the characters which are not allowed in the type. I guess, this is why you are not seeing any error when you try to cast the data into json.
